# Magento 2.0.3 fresh install unable to change to developer mode following step by step developer documentation

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

i just did an fresh install (web installer) of magento 2.0.3. When trying to switch to developer mode by using

> magento deploy:mode:set developer

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

is returning the following failure:

> There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check file permissions for the Magento code for the user under which you are executing this command.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... sudo <magento_user> php deploy:mode:set developer  solved the Problem!

Answer (score 0):

use below command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

May be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

For me there was an error in my of my custom modules' constructor. For anyone else experiencing this, look through your version control logs about update's you've done recently that may have broken this.